# Katalon - Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, katalon-studio, katalon

I'm using Katalon for Azure DevOps Pipeline.

The yaml is

```
- task: katalonTask@1
testSuitePath="Test Suites/TEST" -executionProfile="default" -apiKey="509XXX-92fb-XXX-af2f-XXXXXXXXXX"'
```

when I run the pipeline I have a log that says

```
Activating...
Start activating offline...
Search for valid offline licenses in folder: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.katalon\license
The number of valid offline licenses: 0
Offline activation failed.
Start activating online
```

so I understand the license is getting online from the API key I received, is this license will expire after a couple of runs?

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have the proper licences:

1. [How to use Katalon for Azure DevOps](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/azure-devops-extension.html#installation)
2. [Grant and Use a Katalon Runtime Engine Offline License](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/re-offline-licenses.html#step-1-users-view-and-send-a-machine-id-to-owneradmins)

Comment: Have you resolve your issue or still not , if yes please share how you can get rid of this license issue?